# Historical data for using supervised learning algorithm in the field of Mechanical Engineering

Tags: mechanical-engineering, design, mechanical-failure, data, failure-analysis

Being a student in the field of Mechanical Engineering, I am very new to Machine Learning.I did a couple of basic online courses of Machine Learning (including the one by Andrew Ng on Coursera). So, I am a bit curious about using Machine Learning in this field.

What I want to know is where can I find monitoring data in large quantities related to the use of any mechanical component  so that I can use it to train and predict results(just for practicing so as to know how everything works)

Also any other tips/tutorials/guidance on how to start working on the combination of these two fields would be helpful.

Comment: This is a "finding things question" which is off-topic for the site.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the data, but currently there is an intensive research on the application of machine learning on solar radiation prediction. Maybe these papers might be useful to you if you can access them.

[The artificial neural network for solar radiation prediction and designing solar systems: a systematic literature review](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0959652615004096)

[Solar radiation forecasting with multiple parameters neural networks](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1364032115003470)

[Comparison of regression and artificial neural network models for estimation of global solar radiations](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1364032115008679)